# pandas/regex: Remove the string after the hyphen or parenthesis character (including) carry string after the comma in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a dataframe contains one column which has multiple strings separated by the comma, but in this string, I want to remove all matter after hyphen (including hyphen), main point is after in some cases hyphen is not there but directed parenthesis is there so I also want to remove that as well and carry all the after the comma how can I do it? You can see this case in last row.

```
dd = pd.DataFrame()
dd['sin'] = ['U147(BCM), U35(BCM)','P01-00(ECM), P02-00(ECM)', 'P3-00(ECM), P032-00(ECM)','P034-00(ECM)', 'P23F5(PCM), P04-00(ECM)']
```

Expected output

```
dd['sin']
# output 
U147 U35
P01 P02
P3 P032
P034
P23F5 P04
```

Want to carry only string before the hyphen or parenthesis or any special character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following **regex**:

```
r"-\d{2}|\([EBP]CM\)|\s"
```

**Here is the code:**

```
sin = ['U147(BCM), U35(BCM)','P01-00(ECM), P02-00(ECM)', 'P3-00(ECM), P032-00(ECM)','P034-00(ECM)', 'P23F5(PCM), P04-00(ECM)']

dd = pd.DataFrame()
dd['sin'] = sin
dd['sin'] = dd['sin'].str.replace(r'-\d{2}|\([EBP]CM\)|\s', '', regex=True)
print(dd)
```

### OUTPUT:

```
         sin
0   U147,U35
1    P01,P02
2    P3,P032
3       P034
4  P23F5,P04
```

---

## EDIT

Or use this line to remove the comma:

```
dd['sin'] = dd['sin'].str.replace(r'-\d{2}|\([EBP]CM\)|\s', '', regex=True).str.replace(',',' ')
```

### OUTPUT:

```
         sin
0   U147 U35
1    P01 P02
2    P3 P032
3       P034
4  P23F5 P04
```

Comment: If ```'U147(BCM),  U35(BCM)' ```if there is no space and want to remove comma also .. wanted ```U147 U35``` How can I do it?

Comment: :It is not giving me the space ```U147U35``` showing this way..

Comment: see my new edit

Answer (score 1):

The following code seems to reproduce your desired result:

```
dd['sin'] = dd['sin'].str.split(", ")
dd = dd.explode('sin').reset_index()
dd['sin'] = dd['sin'].str.replace('\W.*', '', regex=True)
```

Which gives `dd['sin']` as:

```
0     U147
1      U35
2      P01
3      P02
4       P3
5     P032
6     P034
7    P23F5
8      P04
Name: sin, dtype: object
```

The call of `.reset_index()` in the second line is optional depending on whether you want to preserve which row that piece of the string came from.

Comment: `dd['sin'] = dd['sin'].str.replace('\W.*', '', regex=True)` would be much better as he also specified all special characters to be removed.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I missed that bit.  Edited my answer to reflect this.  Thanks!

Comment: @Frodnar Sry for my mistake.. I changed the expected output.. I putted in one single line but It was actually on same line. can you help me out?

Comment: @Sam I changed the expected output. Can both of you help me out..